# openpyxl conditional formatting with named style

Tags: python, openpyxl, conditional-formatting

I have a named style, defined with:

```
style = openpyxl.styles.NamedStyle('style1')

style.fill = openpyxl.styles.PatternFill(patternType='solid', fill_type='solid', fgColor='BB0000')

style.border = openpyxl.styles.Border(left=openpyxl.styles.borders.Side(style='thin'), 
                                      right=openpyxl.styles.borders.Side(style='thin'), 
                                      bottom=openpyxl.styles.borders.Side(style='thin'),
                                      top=openpyxl.styles.borders.Side(style='thin') )
```

I want to have a conditional format, based on cell value, that uses this style.

I can do something like:

```
rule = openpyxl.formatting.rules.CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['0']', ...)
```

But this doesn't seem to take a named style. It takes either a differential style, or a fill and a border as separate things...

Comment: Are you familar with [conditional format](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html?highlight=conditional%20format)

Comment: yes, conditional format takes a Rule, which is what I specified there...

Answer (score 2):

You can't use named styles with conditional formats. There are subtle differences in the way they're applied but they are also implemented and stored differently. Just create a `DifferentialStyle` in the same way as a named style and set this as the `dxf` for the rule. You can probably do this very easily:

`dxf = DifferentialStyle(**dict(style))`